# Integral of $\int \frac{ \left( 1 - x^2\right) ^\frac{3}{2}}{x^6} dx$

Tags: calculus, integration

I've done the substitution

$x = \sin\theta$

$dx = \cos\theta \, d\theta$

and end up with

$$\int \frac{\cos^4\theta}{\sin^6\theta} d\theta $$

I'm not sure how to move from there. I'd appreciate any hint.

Comment: What is sen? Maybe you meant sec?

Comment: It was meant to be sin, thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint:

$$\frac{\cos^4(\theta)}{\sin^6(\theta)}=\cot^4(\theta)\csc^2(\theta)$$

and

$$\frac{d}{d \theta} \cot(\theta)=-\csc^2(\theta).$$